# HTML / IOS < 6 Table Alignment

Tags: html, ios5, html-email

Having a little trouble with a HTML email on older versions of IOS in that tables will not align next to eachother. I am creating a responsive email layout for a client and have a need to use align="left" to float tables. ( sample code below )

I have tested on every client i can think of and it is only old IOS versions with this issue.

Sample code: ( this isnt the actual code i am using but same princible )

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" border="0" class="full-width">
    <tr>
        <td width="600" class="full-width">

            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="200" align="left">
                <tr>
                    <td width="200">Some Text Here 1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="200" align="left">
                <tr>
                    <td width="200">Some Text Here 2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="200" align="left">
                <tr>
                    <td width="200">Some Text Here 3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is an image of whats happening with IOS 5 (Incorrect) and IOS 6 (correct):

[Image of IOS 5 and 6 respectively with table included](http://digital-ink.co.uk/uploads/images/site/IphoneIssue.jpg)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. If you need further info let me know.

Comment: What is your responsive CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You have `align="200"` on your table cells - not sure if it is just a typo in the sample code, but that could possibly be messing things up. Otherwise, it looks good to me, maybe try adding `float:left;` to the aligned tables as a fallback to see if it helps.

Also set the width of your table cells to 100% or 200 to make sure they are behaving as expected and check that your full-width class or other css isn't doing anything funky.

Comment: Sorry that was indeed a typo, thanks for the suggestion will give it a go

Answer (score 0):

Right, after hours of playing around with the code the answer is... :

Make sure the container TD also as align="left" so the code would become:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" border="0" class="full-width">
<tr>
    <td width="600" class="full-width" align="left">

        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="200" align="left">
            <tr>
                <td width="200">Some Text Here 1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="200" align="left">
            <tr>
                <td width="200">Some Text Here 2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="200" align="left">
            <tr>
                <td width="200">Some Text Here 3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </td>
</tr>
```